# Can we use ADF to copy data into Google Cloud stoarge

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to utilize ADF for transferring data into Google Cloud storage from a blob folder or export data from a database to Google Cloud storage.

[image]

Error message : The linked service in sink dataset does not support sink.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores) of copy activity connectors,

> Google Cloud Storage only supports as Source of the copy the activity. Currently it is not supported as the sink of the copy activity.

You can see here when I am trying to create GCS sink dataset.

[image]

You can raise the feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).

So, as a workaround try to copy the data to GCS using code via databricks or functions as per your requirement by making connections to both source and target.